# Which library to use for line chart in codenameone ?

Tags: codenameone

I have seen few libraries in codenameone for rendering charts and I don't know the pros and cons of these library. I want to draw line chart with capabilities of pinch zooming, showing values on touching any points. I have seen 2 cn1lib that needs to be attached externally      __ [CN1-Charts](https://github.com/shannah/CN1-Charts), [CN1aChartEngine](https://github.com/shannah/CN1aChartEngine)
 and one that is provided with the codenameone `com.codename1.charts.ChartComponent`. Which one should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should migrate your code to the builtin charts API http://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-charts